# Ajax tool kit text editor sub controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a text editor provided by Microsoft ajax-toolkit.
It renders `iframe` on browser. I have added a dropdown in that editor and I want that when user changes the drop-down index the value should be added in the editor current cursor position.

```
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
  <select id="myOptions">
   <option value="myValue1">My Value 1</option>
   <option value="myValue2">My Value 2</option>
   <option value="myValue3">My Value 3</option>
   <option value="myValue4">My Value 4</option>
   <option value="myValue5">My Value 5</option>
</select>
```

and javascript

```
$.fn.extend({
insertAtCaret: function (myValue) {
    var doc = this[0].ownerDocument;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    if (win.getSelection) {
        var selObj = win.getSelection();            
        var myRange  = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
        selObj.deleteFromDocument();
        myRange.insertNode(doc.createTextNode(myValue));
        selObj.addRange(myRange);
        selObj.collapseToEnd();
        this.focus();
    }
    else if (doc.selection) {
        this.focus();
        sel = doc.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
        this.focus();
    }
    else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
        var startPos = this.selectionStart;
        var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
        var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.innerHTML.substring(endPos, this.innerHTML.length);
        this.focus();
        this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
     }
   }
});

$("#myIframe").contents().find("body").attr("contenteditable", "true");
$("#myOptions").on("change", function() {
    $("#myIframe").contents().find("body").insertAtCaret($(this).val());
});
```

It is working fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Pc55/3/)

But when I changing it to `ul` and `li` it is not working.

```
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
<ul id="myOptions">
    <li value="myValue1">My Value 1</li>
    <li value="myValue2">My Value 2</li>
    <li value="myValue3">My Value 3</li>
    <li value="myValue4">My Value 4</li>
    <li value="myValue5">My Value 5</li>
</ul>
```

script

```
$("#myIframe").contents().find("body").attr("contenteditable", "true");
$("#myOptions").on("change", function() {
    $("#myIframe").contents().find("body").insertAtCaret($(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Pc55/41/)

Edit:- working in Mozila but not working in IE

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code directly into your question.

Comment: @Blazemonger update question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `.val()` to `.text()` when using non-form elements:

```
$("#myIframe").contents().find("body").insertAtCaret( $(this).text() );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5Pc55/46/